# PHP code calling the field in db that does not exist [resulting no display on webpage]

Tags: php, mysql

We have a website that has having trouble accessing Shipping info on all of our product page. The information is pulled from the database called shipping_info

What I see from php code below is it calls parent_id to access the shipping info for a particular product but the parent_id does not exist in the shipping_info table but exist in awt_prod table.

```
$parent_id = $_GET['id'];

if (is_numeric($parent_id)) {
    $parent_id = mysql_escape_string($parent_id);
} else {
    die("<p> Error: Invalid Product ID <br> </p>");

function()
function()

$primary_shipping_query = "SELECT name, wt, length, width, height FROM awt_prods WHERE (p_c_flag ='P' OR p_c_flag ='C') AND parent_id = '$parent_id'";
$sorted_rows = fetchAllRows(mysql_query($primary_shipping_query));
usort($sorted_rows, 'rowCodeNatCmp');

> //Table HTML Header 
</table>

$shipping_options_id_query = "SELECT id, name FROM awt_prods WHERE (p_c_flag ='P' OR p_c_flag ='C') AND parent_id = '$parent_id'";

$shipping_ids = mysql_query($shipping_options_id_query);
$shipping_info_array = array();
$table_id = 0;

while ($part_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($shipping_ids)) {
    $part_skey = $part_id['id'];
    $part_skey_query = "SELECT * FROM prods_shipping_options WHERE part_skey = '$part_skey'";
    $shipping_info = mysql_query($part_skey_query);
    
while ($ship_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shipping_info)) {
        $table_group_name = table_group($ship_row['title']);
        $shipping_info_array[$table_id] = array('table' => $table_group_name, 'name' => $part_id['name'], 'memo' => $ship_row['memo']);
        $table_id++;
    
    }
}

$unique_title_array = array();

//print_r($shipping_info_array);

foreach ($shipping_info_array as $unique) {
    $unique_title_array[] = $unique['table'];
}

$unique_title = array_unique($unique_title_array);

foreach ($unique_title as $shipping_table_name) {
>Some <html><css>
?>
```

My possible solution is to join both shipping_info table and awt_prod table using a Key but I dont know what the key should be or how to approach this possible solution.

Comment: You need to include all relevant code into the question (copy/paste), not as links off-site.

Comment: _"What I see from php file is it calls parent_id to access the shipping info for a particular product but the parent_id does not exist in the database table."_ - Sounds like you've identified the issue so what exactly is your question? What have you tried to do to fix the issue?

Comment: are you aware you posted your mysql connection details for the world to see in that gist?

Comment: You should remove that gist immediately, then change the credentials for your mysql server (since you've just leaked them online). You should also update your code, since it's using the obsolete `mysql_*` extension (deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7). If it still works for you, then you _really_ need to update PHP as well to a version that's still supported.